# Display error messages after migrating from jsf 1.2/richfaces 3.3 to jsf2.1/richfaces 4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

After migrating from jsf1.2/richfaces 3.3 to jsf2.1/richfaces 4 I have a problem displaying error messages.

Here is a message extracted from the log file: `WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Karten ID ein.), detail=(Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Karten ID ein.)].`

```
create_customer.xhtml

<ui:define name="MainContent">
    <h:form id="containerForm">
        <a4j:region>
            <div class="Left">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="CustomerData">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Caption">
                            #{messages['view.label.cardId']}
                            <div class="Needed">*</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="Input">
                            <h:message for="cardId" styleClass="WarningMessage" />
                            <h:inputText id="cardId" styleClass="Standard" value="#{myObjectAction.customer.cardId}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br />
                            <h:panelGroup id="saveButtons">
                                <div class="Left">
                                    <h:commandLink id="saveCommand1" styleClass="bt_kurz" value="#{messages['view.button.save']}" action="#{myObjectAction.createCustomer}" />
                                </div>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </a4j:region>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

My template.xhtml.

```
<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <div class="Menu">
            <ui:insert name="MainMenu"/>
        </div>
        <div class="Page">
            <ui:insert name="MainContent"/>
        </div>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

I'm adding the error messages in my Seam component like:

```
org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages.addToControlFromResourceBundle(invalidValue.getPropertyName(), messages.get(messageKey));
```

When I include the global `<h:messages />` on the xhtml page, then all error messages are shown but still there are no individual ones.

Also I'm using `seam 2.3.1.Final` and running on `Jboss 7`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and act accoridingly. No one is every going to help you with a post like this. (and how is this java-ee or seam related?)

Comment: @Kukeltje Point taken. I edited the question. Regarding the java-ee and seam related, I added them because I suspected that maybe this is not related to pure jsf/richfaces but also on seam/java-ee.